# WPF Richtextbox loaded document paragraph borders

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `UserControl` that basically wraps a `RichTextBox` It looks something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Installers.Ui.Views.Controls.RichTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Theme/ElementsTheme.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="MyRichTextbox" Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColorBrush}" Foreground="{StaticResource GrayColorBrush}" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
            
    </RichTextBox>
</UserControl>
```

I have some styling in the code behind, something that looks like:

```
      public override void OnApplyTemplate()
      {
           base.OnApplyTemplate();

           var text = GetValue(RTFTextProperty).ToString();
           var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(text));
           MyRichTextbox.Selection.Load(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
           
           MyRichTextbox.IsReadOnly = IsReadOnly;
      }
```

This is the outcome:

[image: RichTextBox]

Now on to my question: As you can see there are "Boxes" around some of the text, How can I change the color of them to the background color or how can I remove them entirely?

Comment: How are you displaying the paragraphs that *don't* have boxes around the text?

Comment: Everything is just in RTF format, so I didn't change anything.

Comment: Ah, well then you'll have to manipulate the document at the RTF level using code.  Not exactly an easy thing to do.  Wouldn't you rather just use an editor to modify the original source RTF to remove the boxes?

Comment: so something like word?

Comment: Yep.  ............